# Need help in downloading 340B excel file without Chrome Drivers

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, asp.net-core, selenium-chromedriver

I need to download a 340B file from the below URL.

https://340bopais.hrsa.gov/(X(1)S(dpvryoh4qc002nb5yqbpagab))/reports

I am using the below code, but it has a dependency on the Chrome driver and I want to remove that.

I am trying to download the covered Entity Daily report file. I am not able to find a direct URL to download a file.

[image]

Below is my current code, but it has a dependency on the Chrome driver so want to get rid of that.

```
public async static Task DownloadExcelFileAsync(string downloadFileName, string folderName)
            {
                ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
                chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false);
                chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.directory_upgrade", true);
                chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", folderName);
    
                using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions))
                {
                    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://340bopais.hrsa.gov/(X(1)S(dpvryoh4qc002nb5yqbpagab))/reports");
    
                    driver.FindElement(By.Id("ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkCEDailyReport")).Click();
    
                    // Set the maximum download time
                    var downloadUntil = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
    
                    // Wait for the file to be created.
                    while (!File.Exists(downloadFileName) && DateTime.Now < downloadUntil)
                        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    
                    if (!File.Exists(downloadFileName))
                        throw new Exception($"Failed to download {downloadFileName}");
    
                    long fileSize = -1;
                    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(downloadFileName);
                    while (fileInfo.Length != fileSize && DateTime.Now < downloadUntil)
                    {
                        fileSize = fileInfo.Length;
    
                        // Loop for five seconds
                        var waitUntil = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
                        while (DateTime.Now < waitUntil)
                            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    
                        // Store the new file-size
                        fileInfo.Refresh();
                    }
    
                    if (fileSize == 0 || DateTime.Now >= downloadUntil)
                        throw new Exception($"Failed to download {downloadFileName}");
    
                    driver.Close();
                }
            }
```

Appreciate any inputs.

Thanks.

Comment: selenium? Since you have to click on some buttons

Comment: or phantom.js maybe

Comment: @pm100 Yes, just to click that button, I have to use the selenium drivers.

Comment: how about phantom.js

Comment: phantom.js is not supported anymore.

Comment: If you don't use ChromeDriver, what do you want to use in its place?

Comment: @GregBurghardt, That is my question. If there is any other way and I am not aware of it.

Comment: Each browser vendor has a driver compatible with Selenium. You can use Firefox, Microsoft Edge or Internet Explorer if you have a really old web application. Unfortunately product and tool recommendations are off-topic for StackOverflow, but read [Install browser drivers](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/install_drivers/) from the Selenium website for more information.

Comment: @GregBurghardt: Thanks for the suggestions. My purpose is to avoid dependency on browsers(any).